# How to create a multiple layout for authenticated and guest users in angular using lazy loading

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I am trying to figure out what is the best way to create a multiple layouts for a website i have tried using two components and load other componenets as children

Comment: Please describe more specific what is the 'multiple layouts' you are trying to archive

Comment: you can create two separate components or use *ngIf ="isLoggedIn()" to hide specific elements from unauthenticated users.. Define isLoggedIn() function in auth service..

Comment: @EthanVu the login and the registeration of the website dosent contain the header and the sidebar component while the other componenets has